# Map existing C++ function to JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, libraries

I have a library that I am compiling and creating a fully standalone C++ program. There are two cpp files, one that has the main, the other with all the functionality.

Currently, this program is implemented with a Java ProcessBuilder with args to call the C++ program and the results of that C++ program just simply go out to a file.

Now, I am wanting to get the results of that C++ function that does that work back to my java program. (The results in the C++ function is a double unsigned char array)

So my question is - is there a way to map those existing library functions so that I can call them from my java program directly, AND still keep using that library in the stand-alone way that I currently am, which is through that driver C++ program main()?

I am basically trying to avoid having to compile the same library twice - once for JNI functionality, and once as a standalone C++ program

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna/) will do what you want.

[Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) requires an additional layer of C glue between Java and C++. But *JNA* can access some C functions directly from Java.

You'll probably need to declare your function extern "C". You won't have to recompile the library, but you will have to link it with your C++ main function.

If you had a large C++ class library to expose, then you'd might be interested in SWIG. But for single C function, JNA is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think an exe can export functions similar to a dll (using __declspec(dllexport) on windows), which means you might be able to load it similarly to a jni-dll. (You might need to rename it .dll or .so to have java load it though.)

Answer (score 0):

If loading doesn't work, another way would be to start your program in a separate process as you do now, but give it an command-line option which establishes some kind of shared-memory-area with the Java program.

That would avoid copying the daya back and forth, but might require a small utility DLL loaded by both the exe and the java program, i.e. not simpler. (Not sure if Java can setup shared-memory easily w/o native c calls ..)

*(keeping answers separate for voting/comments/accept granularity)*

Answer (score 0):

Create a JNI wrapper DLL that runs the executable and returns the chars. Alternatively, compile the relevant code into a static library and link it either to a main() function for a standalone program, or to a JNI stub for calling from Java. In-process always better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a proper way to do it would be first to compile your functions into an independent dynamic library (.dll / .so / .dylib).
Then you can :

- write a C++ executable that links against your shared library
- write a Java program that binds to your C++ library thanks to [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/), for instance (or JNA, if you stick to plain old C)